# How do you get the Jsp PageContext from inside the Controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to access the implicit Jsp PageContext from inside my Spring MVC controller. Somehow, it is passed to the JSP template, but what I want is access it from my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the context path. Then add the following import statement:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

Then you can use the following code in your Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/your-path")
public String controllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
   ...
   String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
   ...
   return "your-url";
}
```